# Yammer App for SharePoint width issue

Tags: office-365, office-365-developer, yammer

It seems that the width of the Yammer feed is forced to 400px even when I specify a Web Part width of 580px.  When exploring the HTML via Chrome, I noticed that some inline styles are set that causing this frustrating issue.  I have no idea how these styles are being set.  Has anyone seen this issue before?

```
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title" id="WebPartctl00_ctl55_g_87a689bc_354e_4d62_b37b_d4bd6bed59a1_ChromeTitle" style="width: 400px !important; ">

<div webpartid="87a689bc-354e-4d62-b37b-d4bd6bed59a1" haspers="false" id="WebPartctl00_ctl55_g_87a689bc_354e_4d62_b37b_d4bd6bed59a1" class="ms-WPBody ms-WPBorder noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace " allowdelete="false" allowexport="false" style=" width: 400px !important; height: 818px !important;"><div id="ctl00_ctl55_g_87a689bc_354e_4d62_b37b_d4bd6bed59a1" style="width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;">
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of App Parts in 2013 is most commonly set by the developer of the App Part.  It takes a bit of extra work on their part to make it support dynamic widths. So, that is where your 400px fixed width is coming from. Since it is set with the !importand flag on the element, normal CSS won't override it. The only way you would be able to override it is with JavaScript after the element loads on the page. You could, for instance, use jQuery to set the width in a document.ready event.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the width is set much later than the ready event.  =(  I abandoned the App part and went with Yammer Embed instead.  Thanks for your answer though!